# Run shell command from JavaScript in node-webkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, desktop-application, node-webkit

Is there any way to run shell command from JavaScript in node-webkit?
There is a lot of similar questions, but it didn't help me.

I'm trying to build simple desktop app for listing installed tools.
I've created node module 'tools-v' which is installed globally and works when I run it in command line.
This module run several commands: `npm -v`, `node -v`, `git -v` etc.
I'm on Windows 7.

```
//var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
//var toolsv = (process.platform === "win32" ? "tools-v.cmd" : "tools-v");
$(document).ready(function() {
    //myCmd = "C:\\Users\\win7\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\tools-v.cmd";
    //myCmd = toolsv;
    myCmd = 'tools-v';
    //gui.Shell.openItem('firefox',function(error, stdout, stderr) { });
    //opening Firefox works.
    exec(myCmd,  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        //detached: true;
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        $('#output').append('stdout: ' + stdout)
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm always getting error:
`""exec error: Error: spawn ENOENT""`

I tried spawn instead of exec. I also tried several other commands, beside node module.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this code works. I just didn't built full app, I tested it trough sublime build for node-webkit. Preforming full build with grunt solved every `spawn` issues.